# Can multiple versions of same application can be submitted to Apple for review at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Suppose I have a application version which I submitted to apple for review today which will be released to public say after 3 weeks. Meanwhile I also have a next version which need to be reviewd and released to public after one month.

SO, my question is can we submit two versions of same applications for review at the same time (Before the first one is released to market)?

Comment: Have you contacted Apple about this? I think they'd be the best source of information about *their* model of approval

Comment: I did. But they said they can only answer this to paid registered developer.

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot. You can have 1 version for sale, and 1 in review, at the same time, per unique app id.

Comment: Thnks. This means the first approved version has to be released to public before submitting next version for the apple review?   Any documentation from apple which i can refer for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The first version has to be approved and ready for sale (although, perhaps not necessarily released) before you can submit a new version for review. I have not seen (although that doesn't mean there isn't any) documentation that describes this, but you can sort of tell from the iTunes Connect interface that there is no way to have more than 1 version in review (or waiting for review) at one tiem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But as you see m getting conflicting answers here. As you are saying if the first one is approved and ready for sale (But not released to public), the second version can be sent for approval. is my understanding correct?

Comment: With a version ready for sale, you can then submit another version for review because, if you think of it this way, the "slot" for a version in review is only available when no other version is in review. You can have just 1 version in review at a time. Once an app is reviewed and approved, it moves out of that review slot and moves into the "ready for sale" slot (whether you've released it to the App Store or not). Make sense?

Comment: Yes thats true and same understanding i also have. Just want to ensure that this is correct and apple doesn't have some other way around for this.

Comment: No, they don't. Apple allows just one version of an app to be live on the App Store. If you want to update it, you submit a new version for review. If there is a problem with that binary, before it is approved, you, the developer, can self-reject the binary, and submit a new binary. Once approved, the new binary replaces the previous version in the App Store. Simple model, and considering how many apps are in the App Store, challenging enough for Apple to manage!

Comment: Any changes after TestFlight integration? Could we push into queue two app versions?

Answer (score 6):

No you will have to wait for the first to be reviewed

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but if the first one is approved by that time but its not released to public. Can i submit second one for approval ?

Comment: No. I currently have this situation with my account as we speak. It shows the current released version and the new version there but I would have to release the other one before I'm able to add a new version.

Comment: So you are saying the first version has to be released for sale before uploding next for review..??? Even if the first one is approved and in ready for sale state.??

Comment: I'm kind of confused by that question. When an app is available on the app store it has the state "Ready for Sale". When you have a version that is in that state you can only have one other version that is pending which means its either "in review", "waiting for review", "approved and held for developer release", etc. The version that is in review will have to be published to the app store and become "ready for sale" before you can add a new version for review

Comment: Ready for sale is the state when binary is reviewed/approved by apple. My question is if one binary is in ready for sale state , can we submit other one for review (Before the first one in ready for sale state is released to appstore)?

Comment: I am looking at my account as we speak and "Ready for Sale" is when it is in the app store. I believe you are thinking about being approved and pending release. In that case you cannot submit another version for review until the one which was just approved is in the app store and ready for sale

Comment: Thanks. If you see above answer , mark says we can submit new binary if the first one is in ready for sale state (But not released to appstore).